# Deleting 1 row only in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i have a chatbox that saves all chats in the database but i want to delete some chats(row) in the chat through command.
i can delete all my chats and others chats but my problem is how can i delete 1 row only?
for example i want to delete row id number 3 only and my command is /del3
how can I do that ? btw my language is php.
i just need a little help in detecting the number from the end of the string /del.
thanks in advance........

btw i dont even know how to use the

```
preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$string);
```

Comment: what does preg have to do with SQL?

Comment: use auto_increment ids to make it easy to identify each row maybe

Comment: `DELETE FROM table WHERE id=3` *n'est-ce pas?*

Comment: this almost sounds like an htaccess question !

Comment: one of those "FIIK" type of questions @Drew could it really be that simple?

Comment: don't forget to wedge the chatId=nnn in there @Fred-ii- or you might give it too much of a haircut

Comment: @Drew I hate typing more than 2 characters where I don't have to. They can fill in the rest. Haircut? Never!!!

Comment: @Drew see you at the next baseball game. I've gotta "slide" now. *au revoir!*

Comment: its easy to say DELETE FROM table WHERE id=3 but im looking for custom delete row for example i need to delete row 3 row 5 row 87 in the word of /del3 or /del5 or /del87

Comment: @Marverick Make it a URL parameter: `/del.php?id=3`. Then use `$_GET['id']` and delete that row.

Answer (score 0):

If your command is always like `/del + number` (/del1, /del2, /del3, etc.), then the solution is quite simple:

```
$command = getCommandFromUI();  //Or whatever method you use
$idCommand = str_replace("/del", "", $command);
```

Thus, `$idCommand` should have the number of the ID you are looking for.

Comment: Haha, sorry, I was checking simultaneously another post in VB. I'll edit this right away.

Comment: thank you sir. this is what i've been asking. thank you very much, you save  a lot of my time been looking to google